# KeyStore.getKey() is returning null

Tags: java, encryption

I generated a keystore using keytool with this command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias serverprivate -keystore serverprivate.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -sigalg SHA256withRSA -keysize 2048 -storepass doyouknowdewey
```

The key pass and store pass are the same. Then I extract the public key and insert it into it's own keystore:

```
keytool -export -alias serverprivate -keystore serverprivate.jks -file temp.key -storepass doyouknowdewey
keytool -import -noprompt -alias serverpublic -keystore serverpublic.jks -file temp.key -storepass public
```

Now I create an InputStream in java with a keystore and create a KeyStore object:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("keys/serverprivate.jks");
KeyStore serverPrivate = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
serverPrivate.load(is, "doyouknowdewey".toCharArray());
```

And I extract the key to make a cipher instance so  can encrypt and decrypt the text:

```
Key key = serverPrivate.getKey("serverprivate", "douyouknowdewey".toCharArray());
```

This all works fine, and I can encrypt data with the private key. But if I try decrpyting/encrypting with the public key, the `Key` object is null:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("keys/serverpublic.jks");
KeyStore serverPublic = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
serverPublic.load(is, "public".toCharArray());
Key key = serverPrivate.getKey("serverpublic", "public".toCharArray());
if(key == null) {
    System.err.println("Key is null");
} 
//returns null
```

So how do I make this work?

EDIT:

Apparently serverpublic isn't a key, but a certificate. I found out by running `serverPublic.isKeyEntry("serverpublic");`, which returned false, while `serverPublic.isCertificateEntry("serverpublic");` returned true. So I changed the code to this:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("keys/serverpublic.jks");
KeyStore serverPublic = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
serverPublic.load(is, "public".toCharArray());
Certificate cert = serverPrivate.getCertificate("serverpublic");
if(cert == null) {
    System.err.println("Key is null");
}
```

This doesn't return null any longer. But when I run this, `cipher.init` still throws a nullpointer exception:

```
Cipher cipher;
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, cert);
```

Comment: In the call `serverPublic.load(is, "publi".toCharArray());`, is "publi" a typo?

Comment: What is the implementation of `serverPrivate.getKey`?

Comment: The last code sample loads the keystore into `serverPublic` but reads the key from `serverPrivate`.

Comment: @jsheeran Yes this was a typo, it's not actually in the code. I edited it

Comment: @Robert no it doesn't?

Comment: Why don't you simply export a certificate with the public key with `keytool -export -keystore serverprivate.jks -alias serverprivate -f  Example.cer`

Comment: well, now it is the standard `NullPointer`-Error: `cipher` is not initialized! I wonder the compiler is not indicating this...

Comment: @gil.fernandes because this is eventually supposed to become an SSLSocket, which needs a truststore, and this is only one line more work

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger Thank you! It's working now.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I'm using eclipse, I don't know why either.

Answer (score 1):

serverpublic wasn't a key, but a certificate. I had to load it using

```
Certificate cert = serverPrivate.getCertificate("serverpublic");
```

and then call

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, cert);
```